# Ignore all text between HTML tag JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression that is running on a string of HTML, but I need to exclude anything that is between a `<p></p>` tag from being able to match with my regex. Is there a way of doing this in my current regex?

My regex (matches: $, %, decimal, and whole number values in a string): `/(?:\$?)(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\%?)|\d+)(?:\.\d+(?:\%?))?/g`

Basically, this regex should match with the following.

```
<div>$50</div>
<p>$40</p>
<div>$30</div>

matches: $50 & $30
ignores: $40
```

Comment: you can improve your original regex a bit
/(?:\$?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?\%?)/g will do the same job https://regex101.com/r/FKG0d8/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/(?<!<p>[^>]*)(?:\$?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?\%?)/g`
will work on most browsers see https://regex101.com/r/vqZ6GO/2

I wrote **most** because negative Lookbehind is still not officially supported in **all** browsers but is supported in chrome edge and firefox on all supported versions.

full list [Here](https://caniuse.com/?search=lookbehind)

`/(?:\$?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?\%?)(?![^>]*<\/p>)/g`
will work on all browsers as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/FKG0d8/5)

Comment: Is there any way to span this over multiple lines?

Comment: /(?:(?:\$?)(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\%?)|\d+)(?:\.\d+(?:\%?))?(?![^>]*<\/p>))/gs
https://regex101.com/r/YMoe12/4

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DOMParser` to convert your string to Html and then use `querySelectorAll` and `forEach` to remove the `p` tags from your document and then use your `regex`:

```js
const htmlString = "<div>$50</div><p>$40</p><div>$30</div>";
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlString , "text/html");
doc.querySelectorAll('p').forEach((a) => a.remove());
console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
//do your regex captures with the doc.body.innerHTML
const matches = doc.body.innerHTML.match(/(?:\$?)(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\%?)|\d+)(?:\.\d+(?:\%?))?/g);
console.log(matches);
```

[DomParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

Comment: This seems like it would work, but I cannot use the DOM (using angular).

Comment: @WyattH7 Angular is still javascript, this is a DomParser object, you could very well use it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookahead and lookbehind with an alternate to a exclusion class. There are two regexes:

1. Matches `$,.%` and numbers only within HTML tags except for `<p>` tags.
2. Matches `$,.%` and numbers anywhere except within `<p>` tags.<sup>✼</sup>

**Figure I**

```
/(?<=<|[^p]>)[$.,%\d]+(?=<[^p])/g
```

**Figure II** <sup>✼</sup>

```
/(?<=<|[^p]>|\/p>)[$.,%\d]+/g
```

**Figure III**

| Segment | Description | Alternate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `(?<=` | Start lookbehind - everything within the parenthesis of a lookbehind must match in order for whatever is after it to match. The lookbehind itself is not consumed (it isn't included in the results). |  |
| `<|` | Match a literal `<` OR... |  |
| `[^p]>` | ...anything ***but*** a literal `p` - followed by a literal `>`. |  |
| `|p\/>` | ...OR a literal `p/>` <sup>✼</sup> | #2 |
| `)[$.,%\d]+` | End lookbehind - match any number of `$.,%` or number. This is a naïve expression assuming that the matches are in a logical and grammatically correct format. |  |
| `(?=<[^p])` | Lookahead - everything within the parenthesis of a lookahead must match in order for whatever is before it to match. The lookahead itself is not consumed (it isn't included in the results). Match literal `<` and anything ***but*** a literal `p`. | #1 |

#1 [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QBh0wu/2)
#2 [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pKGJTs/2)<sup>✼</sup>

<sup><sup>✼</sup>Added alternate criteria per yuhsef's comment.</sup>

```js
let str = `<div>$50.25</div>5.00<p>$100.00</p>150%<div>1,000%</div>2,000`;
const rgx1 = /(?<=<|[^p]>)[$.,%\d]+(?=<[^p])/g;
const rgx2 = /(?<=<|[^p]>|\/p>)[$.,%\d]+/g;

const matchesA = str.match(rgx1);
const matchesB = str.match(rgx2);

console.log(matchesA);
console.log(matchesB);
```

Comment: you are missing a few requirements he had in his question
/(?<=<|[^p]>|\/p>)[$.,%\d]+/g  will cover all is requirements in your way https://regex101.com/r/JW8QNB/1

Comment: Ah, I didn't see any criteria that requested numbers outside of tags to match. I'll update to include both ways, thanks.